# Move two items of array to front in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `address` like so

```
[
    {
        id: "83",
        country: "China",
        type: "NORMAL"
    },
    {
        id: "84",
        country: "California",
        type: "HOME"
    },
    {
        id: "85",
        country: "Brazil",
        type: "NORMAL"
    },
    {
        id: "86",
        country: "India",
        type: "WORK"
    },
]
```

How I move two items with `type` is HOME and WORK to the front of array like so: `HOME` first then come `WORK` then another.

```
[
    {
        id: "84",
        country: "California",
        type: "HOME"
    },
    {
        id: "86",
        country: "India",
        type: "WORK"
    },
    {
        id: "83",
        country: "China",
        type: "NORMAL"
    },
    {
        id: "85",
        country: "Brazil",
        type: "NORMAL"
    },
]
```

Thank you :))

Comment: you need `sort`. BTW what have you tried yet?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @gorak: You don't *need* sort, especially if the goal isn't actually sorting (which it may *appear* to be, but hasn't been explicitly stated).

Comment: try `your_array.sort(e => e.type != "HOME" || e.type  != "WORK")`

Comment: oh, your code work perectly. @marmeladze

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use JS array sort method, I provide you an example below (pseudo code):

```
const order = ['HOME', 'WORK', 'NORMAL'];
const arr = [{id: "83", country: "China", type: "NORMAL"}, {...}] // your array to sort
const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.type) > order.indexOf(b.type));
```